# MySQL load data infile with matching headers

Tags: mysql, csv, import, data-import

Here's my current situation:

- I have CSV files with X columns.
- I have empty SQL database with Y columns.

Problem:

- CSV files may contain columns the SQL database does not have.
- SQL database may contain columns/vars the CSV file does not have.
- CSV files will have Z matching columns with SQL database; solely identifiable through row 1 (headers). They are not identifiable through order.
- Can't use a GUI like HeidiSQL. Need command-line solution.

I want to upload the CSV file into the empty database; leaving all variables that are missing in the CSV file blank. How does one go about and do that? My attempts are resulting in MYSQL assuming the columns are ordered in the same way as the database.

Answer (score 3):

Up to a certain point you can use MySQLs [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) syntax. A fully configured example might look like this (skip one line, insert into `col1` and `col3` of your table):

```
load data local infile '/path/to/your.csv' 
into table `yourdb`.`yourtable` 
fields escaped by '\\' terminated by '\t' 
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines 
(`col1`, `col3`);
```

If you have csv data you don't want in your table... either add some columns in your table for them and delete those columns afterwards or remove them from your csv in the first place.

If it gets any trickier than that, you'll almost certainly have to code it in a programming language of your choice.